# Como fazer 'efeito' radio em div

Tags: html, jquery

Preciso fazer um efeito igual de input radio porém na div, pois quando clicar na primeira div adicionar uma class, se clicar em outra div também adicionar uma class porém tem que remover da div que recebeu a class a primeira vez.

Comment: Não está claro a pergunta Eduardo, poderia explicar com algum exemplo mais claro?

Comment: em input radio quando você clica nele, ele deixa selecionado porém se você clicar em outro input radio ele remove do que você clicou e adiciona na onde teve um novo click. Certo? Preciso fazer isso em div. 
 
exemplo:
<div>
 a
</div>
<div>
 b
</div>

se clicar na A adicionar uma classe
se clicar na B adicionar uma classe (porém tem que remover da A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo bem simples utilizando JQuery

```js
$("div").on('click', function(){
  $('div').removeClass('selecionado');
  $(this).toggleClass('selecionado');
});
```

```css
div{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.selecionado{
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você precisa relacionar as divs e para isso eu recomendo um atributo data. Assim ele cumpre seu papel e você não mistura o controle da ação com a sua classe responsável pelo formato. O grupo também serve para você aplicar a ação em somente algumas divs e mudando o value do atributo você pode aplicar várias vezes na mesma página.

No exemplo abaixo eu escolhi o atributo "data-group", mas poderia ser data-salsicha. Também escolhi o valor "meu-grupo", mas poderia ser qualquer coisa também. O importante é você definir um bom nome para ficar claro a funcionalidade.

```
<div data-group="meu-grupo">Primeiro</div>
<div data-group="meu-grupo">Segundo</div>
<div data-group="meu-grupo">Terceiro</div>
```

Agora que todas as divs tem um relação você pode controlar o click com jQuery.
Note pelo seletor jQuery que estou pegando todas as divs que tenham o atributo data-grupo com o valor igual a "meu-grupo". Então cuidado na hora de mudar o nome e valor do atributo.

```
$("div[data-group=meu-grupo]").on('click', function(){
   // Removemos a classe de todas as divs do grupo
   $("div[data-group=meu-grupo]").removeClass("minha-classe");

   // Agora adicionamos a classe somente no item clicado
   $(this).addClass("minha-classe");
})
```